# Resize Named Range VBA

Tags: vba, range, named

VBA
Excel 2016

I'm trying to dynamically resize a range if the number of columns is less for that range after some code is executed. Referenced the MS files and various online examples with no luck. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193274.aspx

I can achieve the correct resize only if I do something like "testRange.Resize Range("A1:G1"). However I am looking for something along the lines of:

```
Sub Test_Range()

  Dim Test As Worksheet
  Set Test = Worksheets("test")

  Dim testTable As Range
  Set testTable = Test.Range("testTable[]")

  Dim testTableWidth, testNumbersWidth As Integer
  Set testTableWidth = testTable.Columns.Count

  'Some code
  'testNumbersWith is defined here

  If testNumbersWidth < testTableWidth Then
    testTable.Resize(, testNumbersWidth)
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If the `.Range("testTable[]")` is a Table (not just a Range) then it should update automatically, you can access the Table data in VBA (e.g. `Set testTable = Test.ListObjects("testTable").DataBodyRange`). Not enough details to help what problem you are facing. Alternative use a Named Range with some formulas.

Comment: Patrick - to add more detail, i'm re-populating the top row of the testTable with testNumbers. If the number of testNumbers is less than the previous iteration I want to have the table automatically resize to the smaller number of columns. What i'm seeing is the range stayed the original size and the extra columns are labelled "Column10, 11, etc"

Answer (score 3):

The  method to resize a "Named Range" is different if it is a "normal" named range or a "Table" (ListObject) range. Your title refers to the first case but from your code it seems you are working with a table.

For the case of a named range, you change the scope like this (i.e. to change the number of columns):

```
With ThisWorkbook.Names.Item("testTable")
    .RefersTo = .RefersToRange.Resize(, newColumnsCount)
End With
```

For the case of a Table (`ListObject`), which seems to be your case, you can change the number of columns like this:

```
  Dim testTable As ListObject             ' <-- Declare as ListObject
  Set testTable = Test.ListObjects("testTable")
  ' Or Set testTable = Test.Range("testTable")

  'Some code
  ' ....

   testTable.Resize testTable.Range.Resize(, newColumnsCount) ' <-- resize number of cols
```

Comment: ASH - Much appreciated for the feedback. You're correct...i'm working with a "table" as opposed to just a named range. I haven't worked with the ListObject variable much so I'll have to read up on that.

Comment: For the case of the named range, is there a method to achieve the same without using `with`? @A.S.H.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your other code `.ClearContents` on some columns in the Table (ListObject), say originally you have this:

[image: OriginalTable]

Then lets say some code clears the content of columns D and I (headers C and H):

[image: 2 Cols ClearContents]

Running the code below will remove those columns from Table (by deleting the entire column). You can then use the list table's `.DataBodyRange` to access the table data only.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TableResize()
    Dim oTable As ListObject, oRng As Range, sColsToDelete As String
    Set oTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    For Each oRng In oTable.HeaderRowRange
        Debug.Print oRng.Address(0, 0), oRng.Value
        If oRng.Value Like "Column*" Then
            Debug.Print "Column " & oRng.Column & " to be deleted"
            ' Note order to delete is reversed!
            If Len(sColsToDelete) > 0 Then sColsToDelete = "," & sColsToDelete
            sColsToDelete = oRng.Column & sColsToDelete
        End If
    Next
    If Len(sColsToDelete) > 0 Then DeleteCol sColsToDelete
    ' Example to access the data ranges
    For Each oRng In oTable.DataBodyRange
        Debug.Print oRng.Address(0, 0), oRng.Value
    Next
    Set oTable = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteCol(sList As String)
    Dim oItem As Variant
    For Each oItem In Split(sList, ",")
        ActiveSheet.Columns(CLng(oItem)).Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

The result of the `TableResize` execution:
[image: Result]